# Button click not changing the .html in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Can someone tell me what is happening, why my counter in `id="love"` is not increasing  when  button with `id="buttonattr"` is clicked, here's my code :

```
<button class="btn btn-default buttonattr"style="font-family:Pangolin"   onclick="myhit(\''+this["post"]+'\',\''+this["love"]+'\');myclick()"><span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart fa-lg notactive" ></span> Love</button><pre id="love">'+this["love"]+' students<i  class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart fa-lg" style="color:red">
```

for script:

```
    var toAdd=1;var newValue=0;
var overall=1;
function myhit(post,love){

oldValue=parseInt(love);
if(toAdd>0){
 newValue= oldValue + toAdd;
}
else{
 newValue=overall+toAdd;
}
toAdd *= -1;
 overall=newValue;
$.post('porthome4_.php',{post1:post,love:newValue},function(info){});
}
function myclick(){
$('.buttonattr').click(function(){
$(this).find('#love').html(overall);
$(this).find('#love').append(' students<span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart fa-lg "a style="color:red" ></span>');
 });
}
```

Comment: My value in id="love" is not changing

Comment: Can you put correct HTML. Seems it's incomplete and not well-formed?

Comment: Thank u all for your support ,,the problem was in find("#love")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `click()` event after the DOM ready state:

```
$(function() {
   // Handler for .ready() called.
   $('.buttonattr').click(function(){
     $(this).find('#love').html(overall);
     $(this).find('#love').append(' students<span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart fa-lg "a style="color:red" ></span>');
   });
});
```

Comment: I want to call myclick() function from id="buttonattr" only

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery should be wrappered with

```
$(document).ready({ 
//code here
})
```

This ensures the document is ready before registering Dom events.

[Jquery Document Ready Explanation](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function myclick(){
    $('.buttonattr').click(function(){
        $(this).find('#love').html(overall);
        $(this).find('#love').append(' students<span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart fa-lg "a style="color:red" ></span>');
    });
}
```

The binding of the click event is done in a function.
That means that as long as you don't call that function, it's as if you never wrote that code above.

Remove that `myclick()` function and it may work.

Put that whole code in a `$(document).ready()` and it will be even better, since nothing would happen before the DOM is fully loaded, reducing the possibility that some event binding is attempted before the elements that should be bound are loaded, preventing them for being bound :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // Your code here
});
```

Comment: But I want to call myclick() only after id="buttonattr" is clicked ,and I tried but that too didnt work ,,may be becuase buttonattr is already binded by onclick listener

Comment: I noticed, he doesn't need ready(), as the function myclick() being called explicitly on onclick event

Comment: How do you intend to know that `#buttonattr` has been clicked so that you can call `myclick()` ?

Comment: If you call `myclick()` directly from inline JavaScript when `#buttonattr` is clicked, the function containing a call to `click()` on `#butttonattr` it only binds the event to the button. in that case, you need to click one more time for it to work, except if you have bound a click on your button and calling `myclick()` through another `click()`. In that case, you'll need to add `$('#buttonattr).unbind("click");` at the begining of `myclick()`.

Comment: I used a `alert` in `myclick()`and `myhit()` and they both worked just after one click ,,that means they both  work simultaneously...so i dont need to unbind my `myclick()`,,,,plzz help to solve this issue I would be very great if you help me to work `myclick()` function..